# In Hana query of a CTE, why does type conversion fail in WHERE clause (though it succeeds in SELECT clause)

Tags: type-conversion, common-table-expression, hana

The Hana query below works without the WHERE clause and returns a sum of 60.  With the WHERE clause, it gets this error: "SQL Error [339] [HY000]: SAP DBTech JDBC: [339]: invalid number: not a valid number string '10,30' at "to_decimal" function (at pos 538)".

- It fails whether I use TO_NUMBER or CAST(AS NUMBER).
- It fails in DBeaver and Hana Studio.
- The Hana version is 2.00.051.00.1596053985.
- Similar Oracle and Teradata queries (with the WHERE clause) succeed and return a sum of 50.

```
WITH details AS (
  SELECT 2 AS n_vals, '10,30' AS vals FROM dummy UNION
  SELECT 1 AS n_vals, '10'    AS vals FROM dummy UNION
  SELECT 1 AS n_vals, '20'    AS vals FROM dummy UNION
  SELECT 1 AS n_vals, '30'    AS vals FROM dummy
)
,one_value AS (
  SELECT n_vals, vals
  FROM details
  WHERE n_vals=1
)
SELECT sum(to_number(vals)) AS total FROM one_value
WHERE to_number(vals)>=20
;
```

Comment: It's the final WHERE clause that's the problem.

Comment: I think your question can be simplified to a query without CTE. The error seems logical. What do you ask exactly? Why HANA behaves differently from other databases? Or just how to achieve your query in HANA? One important point is that you should first define tables with the right data types, summing strings is not a good idea, better use numeric columns (of course, this doesn't apply if you just use existing tables). In the `WHERE` clause, you could use a `CASE` to select only values with only numeric digits, and convert to numeric and test it in that case.

Comment: Thanks, Sandra.  The simplified code is useful only in demonstrating an issue I ran into with a CTE in more complex circumstances. Removing the CTE defeats the purpose of the demo. "Vals" is a comma-separated list of numeric values, so the appropriate data type is a character string. The one_value CTE returns only rows with a single value (so no commas, just digits in the strings). The main query converts them to numbers and sums them. The SELECT clause works, and the WHERE clause should work, too. Testing in other databases confirmed this. I think the Hana failure represents a bug in Hana.

Comment: I realize now my example could have been better.  I should have used a different delimiter like vertical bar |, ​and named my variable "vals_list".  Hopefully it is clear now that the comma is intended as a list delimiter, not the European decimal marker.  Sorry about that!

Comment: It was clear to me that the column contained comma-separated values ;-)

Comment: The answer is at the end of Lars' comments that he added to his original answer: "This bug has been reported for HANA 2.00.54."

Comment: In fact, Lars answer may lose future visitors because the first part about commas is off-topic. I better understand the answer in the SAP Community, thanks to Jörg, that a test with CTE works differently from a test without CTE, and "that's bad".

Comment: Well, yes, I think it would have been better if the correct answer had been given separately, rather than as comments added to the original answer.  My hope was that my comment above would help clarify the situation.

Jorg's answer in the SAP community showed that the ROW engine (versus the COLUMN or HEX engine) has the bug.  He did this by converting the first CTE to ROW and COLUMN tables.  But it's still a CTE-related bug; specifically, the ROW engine's handling of the one_value CTE.  Thanks!

Comment: Juat to clarify: Joerg's insight was that when using values in a table instead of a CTE the error does not occur. He did not connect this to the different execution engines. I made that connection and subsequently asked to have a bug opened. The bug is not directly CTE-related - as the main factor is the ROW engine usage here.

Comment: Yes, I misspoke (or mis-wrote).  It was your answer that showed the ROW engine was the problem.  If I could edit the entry, I would.  My apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question has been cross-posted and answered here and [in the SAP Community](https://answers.sap.com/questions/13444334/in-hana-cte-query-type-conversion-fails-in-where-c.html).

### Summary

The example statement fails due to a bug in HANA.
This bug occurs when the **HANA ROW engine** is used to execute the statement.

(This bug is *not* directly related to using CTEs in HANA - as the counterexample below shows, the successful query that uses the HEX engine also uses a CTE. The reason for the failing OP query to use the ROW engine is that the values are selected from the `DUMMY` table, which is implemented as a ROWSTORE table in HANA)

If the same values are stored in a **column store** table, either the HEX (or the COLUMN engine) is used to execute the query.

In that case, the statement works without error.
The execution plan for the successful execution shows an "apply conversion only after filtering” step (which is not present when the ROW engine is used).

If the ROW engine is used - as is the case in the provided example - the query execution hits the conversion error

This bug has been reported for HANA 2.00.54.

---

## Analysis / Background information

To reproduce the problem and a working version it is important to see that the example query uses the **ROW engine** in HANA. This can be seen by checking the **execution plan** or the **PlanViz** trace.

By storing the source data in a column store table, the query can be computed by the **HEX** and/or the **COLUMN** engines.

```
CURRENT_DATE    SYSTEM_ID   DATABASE_NAME   HOST    START_TIME                      VERSION                 USAGE      
26 July 2021    HXE         HXE             hxehost 26 July 2021, 8:35:10.037 pm    2.00.054.00.1611906357  DEVELOPMENT

create row table r_dat as (
SELECT 2 AS n_vals, '10,30' AS vals FROM dummy UNION
  SELECT 1 AS n_vals, '10'    AS vals FROM dummy UNION
  SELECT 1 AS n_vals, '20'    AS vals FROM dummy UNION
  SELECT 1 AS n_vals, '30'    AS vals FROM dummy);
  
create column table c_dat as (
SELECT 2 AS n_vals, '10,30' AS vals FROM dummy UNION
  SELECT 1 AS n_vals, '10'    AS vals FROM dummy UNION
  SELECT 1 AS n_vals, '20'    AS vals FROM dummy UNION
  SELECT 1 AS n_vals, '30'    AS vals FROM dummy);
  
with one_value AS (
  SELECT n_vals, vals
  FROM r_dat
  WHERE n_vals=1
)
SELECT sum(to_number(vals)) AS total FROM one_value
WHERE to_number(vals)>=20
;
```

This query uses a **row store** table and the **ROW engine** and **fails**:

```
SAP DBTech JDBC: [339]: invalid number: not a valid number string '10,30' at "to_decimal" function (at pos 132) 


OPERATOR_NAME   OPERATOR_DETAILS                                       OPERATOR_PROPERTIES EXECUTION_ENGINE
ROW SEARCH      SUM(TO_DECIMAL(ONE_VALUE.VALS))                                            ROW
  AGGREGATION   AGGREGATION: SUM(TO_DECIMAL(ONE_VALUE.VALS))                               ROW
    TABLE SCAN  FILTER CONDITION: 
                R_DAT.N_VALS = 1 AND TO_DECIMAL(ONE_VALUE.VALS) >= 20                      ROW
```

On the other hand, the version with data in a **column store** table works:

```
with one_value AS (
  SELECT n_vals, vals
  FROM c_dat
  WHERE n_vals=1
)
SELECT sum(to_number(vals)) AS total FROM one_value
WHERE to_number(vals)>=20
```

This one works...with a nice "post-filter" conversion in **HEX engine**

```
OPERATOR_NAME       OPERATOR_DETAILS                                        OPERATOR_PROPERTIES EXECUTION_ENGINE
PROJECT             TOTAL                                                                       HEX 
  AGGREGATION       AGGREGATION: SUM(TO_DECIMAL(ONE_VALUE.VALS))                                HEX
    COLUMN TABLE    FILTER CONDITION: 
                    C_DAT.N_VALS = 1 AND TO_DECIMAL(ONE_VALUE.VALS) >= 20 
                    (DETAIL: ([SCAN] C_DAT.N_VALS = 1) 
                    AND ([POST-FILTER] TO_DECIMAL(ONE_VALUE.VALS) >= 20))                       HEX
```

---

### Comparing this with the execution in Oracle

The OP reported that the query works fine in Oracle.
This can be verified by checking the Oracle execution plan.

(http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e2ac5e/2350)

```
WITH details AS (
  SELECT 2 AS n_vals, '10,30' AS vals FROM dual UNION
  SELECT 1 AS n_vals, '10'    AS vals FROM dual UNION
  SELECT 1 AS n_vals, '20'    AS vals FROM dual UNION
  SELECT 1 AS n_vals, '30'    AS vals FROM dual
)
, one_value AS (
  SELECT n_vals, vals
  FROM details
  WHERE n_vals=1
)
SELECT sum(to_number(vals)) AS total 
FROM one_value
WHERE to_number(vals)>=20;


 Plan Hash Value  : 2738139054 

------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation        | Name | Rows | Bytes | Cost | Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT |      |    1 |     7 |    8 | 00:00:01 |
|   1 |   SORT AGGREGATE |      |    1 |     7 |      |          |
|   2 |    VIEW          |      |    4 |    28 |    8 | 00:00:01 |
|   3 |     SORT UNIQUE  |      |    4 |       |    8 | 00:00:01 |
|   4 |      UNION-ALL   |      |      |       |      |          |
| * 5 |       FILTER     |      |      |       |      |          |
|   6 |        FAST DUAL |      |    1 |       |    2 | 00:00:01 |
| * 7 |       FILTER     |      |      |       |      |          |
|   8 |        FAST DUAL |      |    1 |       |    2 | 00:00:01 |
|   9 |       FAST DUAL  |      |    1 |       |    2 | 00:00:01 |
|  10 |       FAST DUAL  |      |    1 |       |    2 | 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
------------------------------------------
* 5 - filter(NULL IS NOT NULL AND TO_NUMBER('10,30')>=20)
* 7 - filter(NULL IS NOT NULL)
```

The execution plan shows that operation 5 (`FILTER`) is actually trying to apply the `TO_NUMBER` conversion to the `10,30` value.

But it also shows in the same operation a `NULL IS NOT NULL` expression.
This (short-circuit) evaluates to FALSE and makes the whole *filter* expression evaluate to FALSE. Effectively, this avoids the conversion for the string.

This `NULL IS NOT NULL` expression was not part of the original SQL but was introduced by the query-rewriting in Oracle. Similar to the `[POST-FILTER]` operation in the successful HANA plan.

---

### Aside: HANA text to decimal conversion

In the first iteration of answering this question, it seemed that the conversion of the string with the `.` into a decimal number was actually intended. While this is not the case, the following explains how HANA handles this conversion.

HANA type conversion from character types to numeric types only accepts a full-stop/dot (`.`) as a decimal separator.

Experimenting a bit shows that the allowed pattern looks a bit like this:

```
(((\+|\-)?([[:digit:]])*(\.([[:digit:]])*)?))|((([[:digit:]])*(\.([[:digit:]])*)?(\+|\-)?))
```

So, there may be a **single plus or a minus sign** at the **start** (exclusive) or the **end** of the string, followed by digits.

The digits can have **a single dot** in between and leading zeroes can be omitted.

But neither multiple dots, other delimiter signs (like comma), or currency symbols are allowed.

If the data uses a comma for decimal separator (and maybe a dot for thousand separators), then replacing those strings before the string to numeric conversion is required:

```
SELECT 
    to_decimal (
        REPLACE (
                REPLACE ('1.219.323,34', '.', '')
                        , ',' , '.'
                )
    )
FROM DUMMY
```

This double replacement first removes the dots completely and then turns the remaining comma(s) into a dot (`.`).

If this conversion has to happen more than a few times, one may want to check if you can either turn this into a function or change the source data accordingly.

---

Comment: Thanks, Lars.  Please see my comments to Sandra above.  "Vals" is a comma-separated string.  The only strings being converted to numbers are those where n_vals=1, so those strings have only digits, no commas or periods.

Comment: I really appreciate all the investigation you did (including Jörg), here and at SAP Community especially, where the HANA bug is very well explained. But I'm lost by all the stuff about comma and Oracle in your answer here, as I think it's now off-topic, and future visitors could be lost. Is it possible to include here in Stack Overflow the texts from SAP Community or at least a summary (and maybe remove the off-topic points)? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Fair call, there is a lot of analysis in there that does not directly address the issue. I'll edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: I wouldn't say it is a bug so strictly. Optimizer may choose the order of predicate evaluation, so this error may or may not appear depending on the other query parts. In Oracle this type of error may also appear or not depending on the evaluation order: in this simplified case it will work, but I've faced hundreds of cases when the "wrong" data should be filtered out for subsequent evaluation of not stable expression, but it is not. The same was for HANA in both CE and row engine. Yes, reproducible error or success is expected, but it depends on many factors and *may* vary

Comment: Anyway, I appreciate your deep investigation! It is a very good job and nice example of a detailed answer.

Comment: @LarsBr.  Well thought out and explained answer.